# ADO Connection.ConnectionString does not return back credentials anymore

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I have a legacy ASP application that I need to release on a modern server. It uses ADO with SQLOLEDB to talk to MS SQL Server. It's logging on to SQL with username and password.

The app relies on a peculiar behavior of the ADO Connection object that seems to have changed. These days (in ADODB.Connection.6), when you provide a connection string to a Connection and then retrieve it back, you don't get back an exact copy of the original string; specifically, the username and password are stripped from it, and some extra parameters are added.

It looks like older versions of ADO did not strip the credentials in this scenario; the application would never work if it did, and it works. Question - is this documented? Is there a way to enforce the legacy behavior in new ADO?

I really don't want to downgrade ADO on a shared server.

EDIT: just isolated it to a minimal test case. Works on Connection.2.80 on Windows 2003 (msado15.dll v. 2.82.5011.0), fails on Connection.6 on Windows 2008 (dll v.6.1.7600.17036).

EDIT2: officially, the old MDAC 2.8, which ADO is a part of, is not supported on Vista and higher. So downgrade is not really an option.

Comment: I shouldn't have to say this, but your application really should not rely on this behavior.

Comment: Then introduce a tag called `i-did-not-code-this`. :) Or just `legacy`. I know it should not. But it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably the "Persist Security Info" property. The property is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (assuming you're using the SQLOLEDB provider; but most providers I've dealt with behave the same in this regard). Basically, when this property is set to `False`, sensitive information, such as passwords, will be stripped from the connection string when it is read. Conversely, when the property is set to `True`, the connection string will be returned exactly as it was supplied (including any sensitive information).

I have only found one [blog post](http://www.damirscorner.com/PersistSecurityInfoDefaultValueChangedInWindowsVista.aspx) (but no official documentation) that states that the default value for this property changed from `True` to `False` at Windows Vista, which would correspond with Windows Server 2008. This matches your observations.

It should be noted that the new default of `False` is considered more secure since there is less risk of accidentally revealing sensitive information. The recommended solution here is to re-engineer the application so that it doesn't need to rely on getting the password back from the `ConnectionString` property.

With that disclaimer out of the way, you can explicitly set the "Persist Security Info" property through the connection string by adding `;Persist Security Info=True`. It may also be possible to set the property on the `Connection` object before opening it (in case you can't change the connection string), but I'm not entirely sure if that would work (you may have to manually set the `Provider` property first).

```
' untested examples

' Method 1
connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
connString = connString & "Data Source=example;"
connString = connString & "Initial Catalog=exampleDB;"
connString = connString & "User Id=user;"
connString = connString & "Password=1234;"
connString = connString & "Persist Security Info=True"

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open connString

' Method 2
connString = "Data Source=example;"
connString = connString & "Initial Catalog=exampleDB;"
connString = connString & "User Id=user;"
connString = connString & "Password=1234;"

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
conn.Properties("Persist Security Info").Value = True
conn.Open connString
```

Comment: That's it. I've already patched the code up to not rely on reading the connection string back (I had other reasons for that, too), but you're exactly right.

Comment: For the record, I ran into the same on an unrelated VB/ADO project which misbehaved under Win7, and "Persist Security Info=True" was exactly the needed magic pill. I'd +1 once again if I could.